# Where can I see custom event data, sent to Google Analytics using analytics.js, within the Google Analytics web app?

Tags: google-analytics

I have some events that I send data to Google Analytics on such as: `ga('send', 'event', 'download', 'click', 'a pdf download');` in an onclick for a download link.

Within the dashboard for my Google Analytics account related to this website, where can I see the data associated with these custom events? (Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 1):

'Behaviour' -> 'Events' -> 'Top Events' and filter.